# Ember CLI: how to get proxy to override http-mock

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

In Ember CLI, if an http-mock endpoint is defined, I can't get the proxy setting to override it.  For example:

At the beginning of the project, I run ember CLI like this:

```
$ ember s --proxy http://localhost:3000
```

Then my API calls to `/api/leads` gets proxied to `http://localhost:3000/api/leads` successfully.  But once I add an http-mock, the http-mock will always rule:

```
$ ember g http-mock leads
```

Even if I run Ember CLI with the proxy setting (`ember s --proxy http://localhost:3000`), calling `/api/leads` will always be handled by http-mock and won't get proxied.  The only way that I can get the proxying working again is to delete the leads http-mock.

Is there any way to get the proxy setting to override http-mock?  I'd like to toggle between using http-mock and the proxy while the 'real' API is being developed, and I was hoping that simply setting the `--proxy http://localhost:3000` will allow me to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Node's environment variable to disable http-mock.  In /server/index.js, add this near the top:

```
  if (process.env.DISABLE_MOCK === 'true')
    return;
```

/server/index.js should now look something like this:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  var globSync   = require('glob').sync;
  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  var mocks = globSync('./mocks/**/*.js', { cwd: __dirname }).map(require);
  var proxies    = globSync('./proxies/**/*.js', { cwd: __dirname }).map(require);

  if (process.env.DISABLE_MOCK === 'true')
    return;

  // other code here
}
```

Now if we want to disable http-mock and proxy all ajax requests, you can run Ember CLI like this.

```
$ DISABLE_MOCK=true ember s --proxy http://localhost:3000
```

This technique was borrowed from @rwjblue from here: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-disable-http-mock-server-within-environment-config-file/6660/5

Comment: @jkym, the issue that you linked to is about http-mock crashing.  Does it also cover http-mock disabling?

Comment: Sorry - the issue I linked to got sidetracked into a discussion about bypassing http mocks if a proxy is declared, or including some kind of flag to bypass the http mocks. The Ember Core member who said "Hopefully we can get it sorted out for 0.2.0 release" probably wasn't talking about the issue at hand. Comment deleted.